# Search an object array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

What is the easiest way to search an `ObjectArray` in Kotlin by a property belonging to that Object?

For example I have a data class

```
data class Cat(
    var name: String,
    var age: Int,
    var type: String,
)
```

and I have a `Array<Cat>` and would like to find the first occurrence of a cat with `age == 4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`find`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/find.html) function to find the element with `age == 4`:

```
val cats = arrayOf(
        Cat("Name1", 2, "Type1"),
        Cat("Name2", 4, "Type2")
)
val cat: Cat? = cats.find { it.age == 4 }
```

`find` function returns the first element matching the given predicate, or `null` if no such element was found.

Comment: Related functions are [`first()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html), which throws an exception if not found; and [`firstOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-or-null.html), which behaves like find() but may be clearer to read.